# Restrict the user on google map

Tags: android

I have the google map implemented in my application,and also have the search facility to search for the location, but I want to restrict the user to search within the specified country,

e.g. let's say the specified location is the UK, so user should not be able to search the location other than the locations within the UK

Comment: ohhh,sorry .
This one is correct,i have the google map implemented in my application,and also have the search facility to search for the location,but i want to restrict the user to search within the specified country,any help will appriciated,
e.g  let's say the specified location is the UK, so user should not be able to search the location other than the location's within the UK

Answer (score 0):

i have a simple solution for this, am using distanceBetween() method to restrict the user with in 30kms radius.

```
float[] distance = new float[1];
Location.distanceBetween(double startLatitude, double startLongitude,
    double endLatitude, double endLongitude, distance);
```